# OpenSHMEM on multiple linux machines

Tags: google-compute-engine, global, partition, address-space

Is it possible to run OpenSHMEM on multiple Linux machines? I want Google Compute Engine VMs to work as PEs in OpenSHMEM.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question, yes.  OpenSHMEM typically operates on cluster compute nodes using an (RDMA-capable) interconnect, e.g. Infiniband, although many implementations support intra-node and other networks.